# Comparing performance of OLEDB and Ado.Net

Tags: c++, sql-server, oledb

I'm trying to get similar performance to Ado.Net with OLEDB but without success.
The best I can get is 50% slower than Ado.Net so I think i'm doing something wrong. I need a forward only reading of recordset, no need to update.

```
    ADODB::_ConnectionPtr con;
    con.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ADODB::Connection) );
    con->ConnectionString = "...";
    con->Open("", "", "", ADODB::adConnectUnspecified);

    ADODB::_RecordsetPtr rs;
    rs.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ADODB::Recordset) );

    rs->Open(bstr_t("select * FROM BigTable"), _variant_t((IDispatch *)con), ADODB::adOpenForwardOnly, ADODB::adLockReadOnly, ADODB::adAsyncFetch);

    rs->MoveFirst();
    int count=0;

    while (! rs->EndOfFile)
    {
        ++count;
        rs->MoveNext();

    }

    rs->Close();
```

I'm using Native Client OLEDB provider.
Is there other option  (excluding .net) to read data in faster way?

Comment: If the table is big, the provider shouldn't matter. Besides, MS announced its intention to make ODBC the fastest option years ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options are

1. Use ODBC: [ODBC database sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ODBC-sample-191624ae)
2. Use OLE-DB from C++: [OLE DB for the ODBC Programmer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810892.aspx), [Creating a SQL Server Native Client OLE DB Provider Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131651.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I modify the ODBC sample, and I get pratically the same performance of Ado.Net. Continue to not understand what I missing in my test code.

Comment: I think the performance problem you're having is because of the overhead of using ADO on top of OLE-DB. I think that either using ODBC or OLE-DB directly (I've added a link to my answer for this) will give you similar performance to ADO.NET.